# ASP.NET MVC Redirection Best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have MVC Controller and Index method that generates a list of Products. Usually, I don't need any parameter and it looks the same.
I need to make redirection from another page, but in this case, I need to show just some of the products according to the parameter that I will send with redirection command.

I implemented it like that:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string param)
    {
      ViewBag.Param = param; //instead of ViewBag can be something else
      return View();
    }
```

On Razor side, I'm checking if I have `ViewBag.Param`
So, that how I can make redirection to the same page with my own parameter. But most of the times it just would be null. 
Just wanted to ask, is this a good practice to use the same view to manage it? Or there is other better solution.

Comment: Using ViewBag itself should be avoided. You should use a strongly typed model to send data to your View.

Comment: it's just for example. Question about to use the same Method

Answer (score 1):

You don't give a lot of detail in your question, but I think what you're trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string param)
{
    SomeClass viewmodel;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
    {
       // get complete list
       viewmodel = GetCompleteList();
    }
    else
    {
       // get list based on param value
       viewmodel = GetListByParam(param);
    }

    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

Then in your calling code, you can choose to pass the param value or not.

```
RedirectToAction("Index", new {param = "hello"});
```

Hopefully, this gets you on the right track.

Comment: thanks. As for me, your implementation pretty much the same as mine. (Since ViewBag is made for this case) But I wanted to ask if it's okay to you the same method Index() with a parameter that would be null most of the time. Or.. It's just better to create sub methods of something else

Comment: Here more imformation. I have a page - Products. I;m showing all products there. Also I have a customers page. And a link - show my products. In this case I want ot redirect user to products page, but show only users products.

Comment: @MishaSloushch That scenario would be a good use case for the optional parameter in the answer. You see this often with paging and sorting.[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761258/sorting-filtering-and-paging-mvc)